# Stereotypes in Enterprise Architect

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

Maybe it's because I'm new to Enterprise Architect I can not cope with stereotypes. I have been using StarUML where stereotypes were assigned to the specific profile which we can load on demand. This functionality allows us to choose stereotypes from certain set (which is needed). 
EA shows huge list of all known stereotypes (occuping whole screen in height) effectively depriving desire to work. Sparx's Help is laconic and is limited to the explanation of the buttons or menu items.

Can somebody give a guidance or indicate link to an article which would help to resolve this issue?

PS I should add that I'm talking about stereotypes C# language like property, enumeration etc.

Comment: enumeration is no stereotype but a datatype.

Answer (score 3):

After a standard installation EA will start up with ALL MDG technologies enabled. Most MDG technologies contain a profile with a couple of stereotypes.

You should only enable the MDG technologies you are planning to use.

Go to `Extensions|MDG Technologies`, select the `None` button and then only select those MDG technologies you need.
[image]

Comment: Really it's possible (to limit). Unfortunatelly EA's functionality in this point seems to be too poor for me. I have come back to StarUML (now I'm trying WhiteStarUML - branch continued by Jan Szpilewski). Its ERD plugin seems to be richer for me, maybe because I'm habituated. It is easy and flexible to customize and develop. I know that EA has own scripting but I don't know it. Thank you for answer!